# C: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to create a struct in a header file, and initialize a template struct. For some reason, when including the header file in multiple files, it gives me the following error:

```
gcc foo.c bar.c -o foo -Wall

duplicate symbol _MYFOO in:
    /var/folders/s4/zyw5lgk92wj9ljnsypgwdccr0000gn/T/foo-52f8fc.o
    /var/folders/s4/zyw5lgk92wj9ljnsypgwdccr0000gn/T/bar-6dc21f.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These are my files:
`Bar.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void helloWorld() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

`Bar.h`

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Foo {
    int number;
} MYFOO = {2};

void helloWorld(void);
```

`Foo.c`

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    helloWorld();
}
```

Interestingly enough, when I remove the line containing

```
MYFOO = {2};
```

The code compiles and works perfectly fine. I believe it has to do with including **Bar.h** twice, which ends up including that struct twice? But how would I avoid something like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After toying around some more, I found the reason for the error coming from the line `MYFOO = {2};`

It had to do with the fact that I was initializing the struct in my header file.
**Header files are meant for definitions, not initializations.**
Instead, the solution for the problem was to simply define and initialize the line in the corresponding source file `Foo.c`.

Now, in that file I included as a global variable:

```
Foo MYFOO = {2};
```

Now to access this variable in any other file, such as in my `Bar.c`, all I needed to do was include the line,

```
extern Foo MYFOO;
```

This solved my problem for compilation and meant that I could use the struct in other files as desired!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a directive to the Bar.h file to check if the file has already been included:

```
#ifndef _BAR_H_INCLUDED_
// Bar.h not included - declare your structs, etc, here.

// Define _BAR_H_INCLUDED_ to indicate this file has already
// been included
#define _BAR_H_INCLUDED_ 1
#endif
```

This should at least prevent you including `Bar.h` multiple times.

EDIT

A better solution might be to include the `Bar.c` from within the `Bar.h`:

```
// Bar.h
#ifndef _BAR_C_INCLUDED_

// code here

// Include Bar.c
#include "Bar.c"
#define _BAR_C_INCLUDED_

#endif
```

You can then simply include `Bar.h` in your `Foo.c`:

```
// Foo.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Bar.h"

int main() {
    //...
```

Then to compile:

```
gcc Foo.c -o Foo
```

So - here is your updated code - first, `Bar.h`

```
#ifndef _BAR_C_INCLUDED_

typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Foo {
    int number;
} MYFOO = {2};

void helloWorld (void);

#include "Bar.c"
#define _BAR_C_INCLUDED_

#endif
```

Now `Bar.c`:

```
void helloWorld() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Lastly, `Foo.c` - include `stdio.h` here as well as `Bar.h` (which will, in turn, include `Bar.c` for us):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    helloWorld();
}
```

And to compile:

```
gcc Foo.c -o Foo -Wall
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm a little confused, since bar.h includes the function prototype, I need to include it in bar.c to define it, and I need to also include it in foo.c to use it? Am I understanding that correctly? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Well, you are un-necessarily including Bar.h twice, what you should probably do is include Bar.c from witihin Bar.h - I'll update.

Comment: Hmmm...did you alter the `gcc` compile command? You were intially including `Bar.c` the first time around, but you don't have to since `Bar.h` is including it for you.

Comment: No. A better solution is to learn how the build process works in the C ecosystem. Including implementation files is not the way to go.